# Store a jQuery selector into a string and use it

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, string, return

The jQuery selector I want to store in a string variable named "jQuerySelector" in Java is :

```
$('h3.icon').parents('.head').find('h5:contains(Input)')
```

Then use it as follows:

```
String result = "return $(\"" + jQuerySelector + "\").get(0);";
```

I am facing syntax error when I initialized "jQuerySelector" as follows and run:

```
String jQuerySelector = "('h3.icon').parents('.head').find('h5:contains(Input)')";
```

My only requirement is to store the above selector query into a string and use it for running the above return statement.

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Use `eval(jQuerySelector)` But that is not advisable. since it may alter the scope during runtime

Comment: There is no variable of type "String" in JavaScript as far as I know.

Comment: I am using it in Java